# Memory access after ioremap very slow

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, driver, performance, kernel

I'm working on a Linux kernel driver that makes a chunk of physical memory available to user space. I have a working version of the driver, but it's currently very slow. So, I've gone back a few steps and tried making a small, simple driver to recreate the problem.

I reserve the memory at boot time using the kernel parameter `memmap=2G$1G`. Then, in the driver's `__init` function, I `ioremap` some of this memory, and initialize it to a known value. I put in some code to measure the timing as well:

```
#define RESERVED_REGION_SIZE    (1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)   // 1GB
#define RESERVED_REGION_OFFSET  (1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)   // 1GB

static int __init memdrv_init(void)
{
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    printk(KERN_INFO "[memdriver] init\n");

    // Remap reserved physical memory (that we grabbed at boot time)
    do_gettimeofday( &t1 );
    reservedBlock = ioremap( RESERVED_REGION_OFFSET, RESERVED_REGION_SIZE );
    do_gettimeofday( &t2 );
    printk( KERN_ERR "[memdriver] ioremap() took %d usec\n", usec_diff( &t2, &t1 ) );

    // Set the memory to a known value
    do_gettimeofday( &t1 );
    memset( reservedBlock, 0xAB, RESERVED_REGION_SIZE );
    do_gettimeofday( &t2 );
    printk( KERN_ERR "[memdriver] memset() took %d usec\n", usec_diff( &t2, &t1 ) );

    // Register the character device
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

I load the driver, and check dmesg. It reports:

```
[memdriver] init
[memdriver] ioremap() took 76268 usec
[memdriver] memset() took 12622779 usec
```

That's 12.6 seconds for the memset. That means the memset is running at ***81 MB/sec***. Why on earth is it so slow?

This is kernel 2.6.34 on Fedora 13, and it's an x86_64 system.

EDIT:

The goal behind this scheme is to take a chunk of physical memory and make it available to both a PCI device (via the memory's bus/physical address) and a user space application (via a call to `mmap`, supported by the driver). The PCI device will then continually fill this memory with data, and the user-space app will read it out. If `ioremap` is a bad way to do this (as Ben suggested below), I'm open to other suggestions that'll allow me to get any large chunk of memory that can be directly accessed by both hardware and software. I can probably make do with a smaller buffer also.

---

See my eventual solution below.

Comment: Is this built as a module (i.e. xyz.ko), or is it compiled into the kernel?

Comment: This is compiled as a module.

Comment: @Dave Post your solution as an **answer** ***not*** as a new part to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ioremap` allocates uncacheable pages, as you'd desire for access to a memory-mapped-io device.  That would explain your poor performance.

You probably want `kmalloc` or `vmalloc`.  The [usual](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch08.pdf) [reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000028) [materials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) will explain the capabilities of each.

Comment: From my limited testing, it seems small chunks of kmalloc'd memory are indeed much faster. But the design here involves the hardware being able to change this memory at will (continuously at ~200mb/sec). Because of this, I thought uncacheable memory would actually be necessary. Am I mistaken there though?

Comment: Different architectures handle coherency of buffers used for DMA differently; Chapter 15 of LDD3 talks about using coherent buffers vs. streaming buffers.  That should explain the basics of how to do DMA while handling the hairy cache issues automatically.  The exact code may have evolved in newer kernels, though.

Comment: The more I read about this, the more I think I'm required to use uncached memory. I'm not doing DMA in the normal sense. The driver calculates the physical address of memory, stuffs that in a register on the PCI device, and the PCI device writes directly to that memory. The user-space app mmap's that memory and accesses it directly with memcpy(). It seems like I'm forced to use uncached memory, and maybe I just need a way to make it faster?

Comment: What you're talking about is a coherent DMA buffer.  If you use the kernel routines for allocating a coherent buffer, the kernel will automatically make it uncacheable if your architecture requires it.  (x86 does not.)  Don't reinvent the wheel; use the functions that are there for this very purpose.

Comment: What's more, if your driver knows when hardware and host cpu will be accessing the data, you can use streaming buffers with the dma_sync_* functions.  This allows caching to stay enabled, but forces a cache flush operation (on archs that require it) as the buffer is about to be handed off from cpu to hardware or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `ioremap()` is what you want there.  You should only access the result (what you call `reservedBlock`) with `readb`, `readl`, `writeb`, `memcpy_toio` etc.  It is not even guaranteed that the return is virtually mapped (although it apparently is on your platform).  I'd guess that the region is being mapped uncached (suitable for IO registers) leading to the terrible performance.

Comment: The idea behind this scheme is to let a hardware device insert data into the memory (via its bus address), and let a user space app pull that data out (after a call to `mmap()`, to access the virtual address). What would be a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I'm updating since I did eventually find a workaround for this ioremap problem.

Since we had custom hardware writing directly to the memory, it was probably more correct to mark it uncacheable, but it was unbearably slow and wasn't working for our application. Our solution was to only read from that memory (a ring buffer) once there was enough new data to fill a whole cache line on our architecture (I think that was 256 bytes). This guaranteed we never got stale data, and it was plenty fast.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this much later :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out doing a huge memory chunk reservations with the `memmap`

The `ioremap`ping of this chunk gave me a mapped memory address space which in beyond few tera bytes.

when you ask to reserve 128GB memory starting at 64 GB. you see the following in /proc/vmallocinfo

```
0xffffc9001f3a8000-0xffffc9201f3a9000 137438957568 0xffffffffa00831c9 phys=1000000000 ioremap
```

Thus the address space starts at  0xffffc9001f3a8000 (which is waay too large).

Secondly, Your observation is correct. even the `memset_io`  results in a extremely large delays (in tens of minutes) to touch all this memory.

So, the time taken has to do mainly with address space conversion and non cacheable page loading.